# How to get distinct records with count in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a print on demand marketplace App on Rails 6 with the current schema.

User has Cart which has many LineItem, where each LineItem belongs to a product. So when a user adds a product to the Cart, a LineItem is created and it is added to the cart. Since it's print on demand, I decided to add separate LineItem for each product to make returns easier to handle.

But I want to aggregate and show the distinct products only on the Cart page with count.

Let's say I have three products PA, PB, PC. I add PA twice and PB thrice to cart. I now have two LA, and three LB. Rather than showing `LA, LA, LB, LB, LB` I want to show `(LA 2), (LB 3)` on the cart page.

The closest I could get to was this query `@line_items = current_user.cart.line_items.select(:product_id).distinct`

Comment: you can group by product_id to get the count. `current_user.cart.line_items.group(:product_id).count`
 But instead of adding multiple LineItem for single product in one cart, introduce `count` column in `LineItem` and have just one line_item for per product per cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rails `group` method for this. Here is how you can get the products grouped by count:

```
@line_items = current_user.cart.line_items.group(:product_id).count.reverse_each.to_h
```